# Django model filter with dynamic field-value pair list

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

If there is a way to pass a list of values which vary in size depending on the values send by the user. This is a fundamental requirement in a user query.

For an example, suppose a model as follows which have 3 fields.

```
class MyModel(models.Model)
   Fiedl1 //say an int field
   Field2 //int field
   Field3 //char field
```

In the user search form all fields are optional and there can be three combinations that user can query for particular objects.

1. User do not set any field in the form (could be handle by default url)
2. User only set values for two fields only.
3. user set all values for the query. (similar to 2)

My understanding is that pass only available fields in the POST request will do the trick. How can I do that? I look for correct and less coding solution for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Q Objects [Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

It would look like this:

```
q_objects = Q() 
for field, value in data:
    q_objects |= Q(**{field: value})

queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(q_objects)
```